# Problem loading Bytearray into XML object. (Flex 4)

Tags: xml, actionscript, flex4

I get Index out of bounds when trying to readObject on my Byte array into the XML object.

```
private var fr:FileReference;
private var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
[Bindable]
private var dataXML:XML = new XML();
```

...

```
public function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            trace("Load Complete");
            data = fr.data;
            dataXML = data.readObject();
        }
```

The Byte array is created by loading a file using FileReference

Answer (score 4):

```
var fileReference:FileReference = event.target as FileReference;
fileReference.data.position = 0;
var xml:XML = new XML(fileReference.data.toString());
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
data = fr.data;
data.position = 0;
dataXML = data.readObject();
```

Comment: I tried this already, still index out of bounds. It seems data.toString() wrapped in an anonymous XML object and assigned to dataXML